# C++ memory leak example via "new"

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm in the process of learning C++, and I would like to understand how `new` and `delete` work for primitive types, and if there is any automatic memory management at all when **not** using smart pointers.

I have written the following code that tries to trigger a memory leak by repeatedly allocating memory for 10'000 integers in the heap (that is, if I understood how `new` works).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int* MemoryLeak(const int size) {
    std::cout << "Allocating space for " << size << " ints..." << std::endl;
    return new int[size];
}

int main() {
    std::string keepGoing = "y";
    while (keepGoing != "n") {       
        std::cout << "Leak memory? [y/n]" << std::endl; 
        
        std::cin >> keepGoing;
        std::transform(keepGoing.begin(), keepGoing.end(), keepGoing.begin(), ::tolower);
        
        if (keepGoing == "y") {
            MemoryLeak(10000);
        } else if (keepGoing != "n") {
            keepGoing = "y";
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have a corresponding `delete` call, so I would expect the memory footprint of my program to grow after each "y" I enter. However, memory footprint stays the same (according to my task manager). Why is that? And how would I have to modify my snippet in order to cause a leak?

Comment: C++ compilers are allowed to optimize your program. In this case it's quite possible that the allocation in the `MemoryLeak` function gets completely removed from your program, since the compiler sees that the memory is never used... godbolt.org is an convenient way of seeing what the compiler actually produces btw...

Comment: Also, operating systems might not actually allocate the virtual memory pages you ask for unless you actually write to those pages.

Comment: Your actual ram usage might not be increasing, but your virtual memory usage definitely is, and this will definitely crash, eventually

Comment: Also, 10 000 `int`s is probably only 40kB, it's hard to see such change in Task Manager. Try `10000000` for increments of 40MB or maybe even `100000000`.

Comment: If we assume that each call of that method takes 1ms, then we'd expect you to run out of virtual memory after... about 14 thousand years.

Comment: *"is [there] any automatic memory management at all when not using smart pointers"* - No. If there was we wouldn't need reference counted "smart' pointers.

Comment: Advice: you don't need **at all** to know about `new` and `delete` to learn C++. Modern C++ idioms don't make use of these and encourage using standard library containers, much more safe.

Comment: @kebs I would _strongly_ disagree. Someone learning C++ should know how to use new and delete _and_ smart pointers and why the latter is preferred in most scenarios.

Comment: @Chris don't get me wrong: what I meant is that there is a **lot** more stuff to learn before starting to get into new and delete. Post-C+11 code makes these almost (99%) useless. And most of the time, its usage is a serious code-smell.

Comment: @Chris Indeed. It's quite helpful to experience the trials and tribulations of `new` and `delete` to better understand the need to avoid them altogether and instead embrace modern C++ idioms. It can also provide a lot of insight when working with the abundance of legacy code that does not or cannot embrace C++11 and above for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious sure, you are right. But lets face it, C++ is a very difficult to language, and learning today one of its features that is clearly dangerous instead of (or before) modern idioms is encouraging having that kind of risky code in the wild for decades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments, your compiler and/or operating system may be optimizing away the problem entirely.

So let's do a few things differently:

- Allocate bigger blocks of memory so that the memory leak, if it exists, is easier to "see."
- Use the return of `MemoryLeak` and write to it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int* MemoryLeak(const int size) {
    std::cout << "Allocating space for " << size << " ints..." << std::endl;
    return new int[size];
}

int main() {
    std::string keepGoing = "y";
    while (keepGoing != "n") {       
        std::cout << "Leak memory? [y/n]" << std::endl; 
        
        std::cin >> keepGoing;
        std::transform(keepGoing.begin(), keepGoing.end(), keepGoing.begin(), ::tolower);
        
        if (keepGoing == "y") {
            int *x = MemoryLeak(10000000);
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) 
                x[i] = i;
        } else if (keepGoing != "n") {
            keepGoing = "y";
        }
    }
}
```

If, as mentioned in comments, we use smart pointers, the memory usage of the program remains constant because when the `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` goes out of scope, it is destroyed and the memory deallocated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int[]> MemoryLeak(const int size) {
    std::cout << "Allocating space for " << size << " ints..." << std::endl;
    return std::make_unique<int[]>(size);
}

int main() {
    std::string keepGoing = "y";
    while (keepGoing != "n") {       
        std::cout << "Leak memory? [y/n]" << std::endl; 
        
        std::cin >> keepGoing;
        std::transform(keepGoing.begin(), keepGoing.end(), keepGoing.begin(), 
::tolower);
        
        if (keepGoing == "y") {
            auto x = MemoryLeak(10000000);
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) 
                x[i] = i;
        } else if (keepGoing != "n") {
            keepGoing = "y";
        }
    }
}
```

*Of course, in practice we would likely not create a unique pointer to an array but rather achieve that effect with a `std::vector`.*